# jquery validate array bidimentional

Tags: jquery, arrays, validation

How validate inputs using jquery validate in this case:

```
<input name="val[0][0]" class="field text">
<input name="val[0][1]" class="field text">
<input name="val[0][2]" class="field text">
<input name="val[n][n]" class="field text">
```

I'm try this: not working

```
$("#form").validate({   

    rules: {
        "val[][]": {
            "required": true,
            "dateBR": true
        }   
    },
```

But "val" can be n..

any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Example: http://jsfiddle.net/NGwY2/
But, the fields "val[][]" are dynamical, i need validate all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you can do it based on the on the dynamic name. However, just looking at the **[jquery validate reference document](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/)** you can create a rule based on a class.

**Example:**

```
$.validator.addClassRules("valReq", { required: true });
```

Comment: In this case it looks like the class would be `field` and the rules object would be `required: true, dateBR: true`